# unset key from associative array in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How would I unset `category[1]` from the below array?

```
Array
(
    [category] => Array
        (
            [0] => add new
            [1] => second
        )
)
```

Can't seem to get the right code.

This is for codeigniter's session class

```
$this->session->unset_userdata($array['category'][$session_id]);
```

is the above correct? or is there something else - that's not working.

Comment: what is the name of the array>

Comment: better you edit your question and be more descriptive what actually you want .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your array name is `$array`:

```
unset( $array['category'][1] );
```

Another way is, `array_pop()`

```
array_pop( $array['category'] );
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  However, is there a way to do this via codeigniters sessions?  `$this->session->unset_userdata($array['category'][$session_id]);` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

```
unset( $array['category'][1] );
```

Assuming you know the array name.

Answer (score 1):

Is this not what you're looking for?

```
unset($arr['category'][1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-splice.php

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what actually you are looking for  , and what user_unsetdata does but i guess you want to unset the array element and you function does same than try pass by reference

```
$this->session->unset_userdata(&$array['category'][$session_id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do a work around hack in CI to accomplish what you want:

```
$SESSION = $this->session->userdata();
unset( $SESSION['category'][1] );
$this->session->set_userdata( $SESSION );
```